# Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and learning through a tutorial about Flutter So I was following the same codes and already tried rewriting almost everything but when I started to run the app and i got that above error.

***ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)***

**Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (14218):**

**My codes:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';


class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {

  void getTime() async {
   Response response= await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/timezone/Europe/London');
    Map data=jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);


  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
        title: Text('here is loading'),
      ),
      body: Text("choose location screen"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this link: https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London.

Not this one:

```
Response response= await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/timezone/Europe/London');
```

The link I gave you above gives you a JSON response in which you decode in your app. You were linking to an actual webpage that doesn't give you a JSON response, that's why you got that error. I have also made it HTTPS so it's more secure in your app.

Comment: Be sure to mark this answer as accepted if it helped you and so others can find the answer if they're facing the same issue.